Why doesn't MSYS Bash evaluate windows exectuable commands as expected?
I've run into a weird behaviour (as usual) where I'm trying to use a Windows executable in a (MSYS) Bash alias, to execute command and handle the results.
The Windows program in question is dumpbin.exe as part of the VS tools, and can be found in the version dependent location:
'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\bin\Hostx64\x64\.
Here is what I am trying to do:
dumpbin /dependents some.exe

So I created a Bash function like this:
function show_deps () {
    local DBPATH='C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\bin\Hostx64\x64\'
    "${DBPATH}"/dumpbin.exe /dependents /nologo $1
}

# show_deps some.exe

Dump of file C:\msys64\dependents
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\msys64\dependents'

So the command runs, but no matter what I try the argument always become "\dependents".
So then I thought to try using the eval command:
DBPATH='/c/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.42.34433/bin/Hostx64/x64/dumpbin.exe'

EXE_ARGS="/dependents /nologo some.exe"; eval "${DBPATH} ${EXE_ARGS}"

# Again same issue: 
...
Dump of file C:\msys64\dependents
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\msys64\dependents'

# So I try without the argument: 
EXE_ARGS="some.exe"; eval "${DBPATH} ${EXE_ARGS}"
...
Dump of file some.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

  Summary

        3000 .bss
        1000 .buildid
        1000 .data
        3000 .debug_abbrev
...
# OK!

So the command works, but not with arguments!
Now here comes the killer...
In Cygwin (with an older Bash version) the same function works!
function show_deps () {
    local DBPATH='C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\bin\Hostx64\x64\'
    "${DBPATH}"/dumpbin.exe /dependents /nologo $1
}

# show_deps some.exe

Dump of file some.exe

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

  Image has the following dependencies:

    cygconfuse-1.dll
    cygwin1.dll
    KERNEL32.dll

  Summary

        3000 .bss
        1000 .buildid
        1000 .data
        3000 .debug_abbrev
        1000 .debug_aranges
        2000 .debug_frame
       13000 .debug_info
        5000 .debug_line
        2000 .debug_line_str
        1000 .debug_loclists
        1000 .debug_rnglists
        1000 .debug_str
        1000 .idata
        1000 .pdata
        3000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
        C000 .text
        1000 .xdata

How can I make this work in MSYS bash?
Can anyone explain what's going on here?
PS. This is completely different to the suggested related question about using git-bash in AWS. This is an MSYS and Cygwin implementation difference.

Have you tried //dependents ?

Try: MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 dumpbin /dependents some.exe, or maybe MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL='*' dumpbin /dependents some.exe

Use cygwin then.

It's funny how SO people keep on marking questions as similar, when they are totally different. People google on what they have at hand. For example if I have an SQLite command issue in Windows, issue, I'm not going to google for relational database expressions on virtual machines. Even if the question and answer is the same. So no, the linked answer is not related.

If the answer is the same, does it really matter that the question is different? Even if we close yours as a dupe, it'll remain as a signpost for anyone who googles the same problem you have.

@HolyBlackCat Well, 1st off the answer is not the same, and then it is the issue about contextual understanding and accessibility. If someone is working in MSYS, why should they go through the pain trying to read about something that is related to AWS and some other tool that they may never have used? I can tell you from experience that nobody will stay on a page for more than 5 seconds if everything on it looks unrelated. Or we can turn the question around. Why do you feel it's so important to mark off questions and answers to have any similarity relation? Point collection?

Because Stack Overflow is not a support forum. It's a knowledge base. Your question is a contribution, as are answers. The target audience are future readers, not question askers. Now if an answer already exists, it's always better to link a question that is asking the same core thing (why do arguments with leading slash not work as expected in MSYS and how to fix that) to those existing answers, so that we don't have an increasing mess of the same answers twice in different places (regarding multiple edits when some update changes them, by the way). - Also, the answers do apply.

If anything, closing as dupes yields less points for people answering questions. "Why ... so important to mark off questions" In theory, so we can maintain a good answer in one place and not paste it around. But in this case, the suggested dupe probably doesn't do a very good job at it.

"So no, the linked answer is not related." - it certainly is. Your problem is that /dependencies is parsed as directory path and converted in an undesired way, and the solution is to either convert the first / to // (and any following slashes, of which you have none, to double backslashes) or use MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1. That issue is literally written in the first line of the question I linked ("The names argument begins with '/'. This is processed by bash as a directory name and results in an error.") and the accepted answer exactly shows these solutions.

I just read your edit about this question being "completely different" to the other question since this is about MSYS and the other is about Git Bash. Git Bash is just the MSYS Bash packaged with Git and it's probably the most widely used way people end up using MSYS. So if you have an MSYS issue, googling "Git Bash " is your best bet. That's how I found the other question, by the way. Also, in that question, the first comment even explains that it's MSYS doing this, the answer also talks about MSYS-specific variables, and the question is tagged msys. (Cygwin is not related!)

The auto-comment said "If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem." and you didn't do that. You just made a blank statement that your question is "completely different" but failed to explain how, and you didn't explain how the answers were not helpful, which is funny because you now even posted your own answer which is proposing the exact same solution (doubled backslash) that the accepted answer in the linked question does.

Your DBPATH uses backslashes as path separator, so first fix this. Path components are separated by forward slashes. Note that a backslash has also special meaning in bash, so you should always be careful, how to use a backslash when doing bash programming.

Embarrassingly, it appears that the default Bash settings in MSYS and Cygwin are interpreting / differently. Most likely because Cygwin accepts Windows paths (C:\the\path) to a certain extent, whereas MSYS does not at all, and a purely relying on POSIX paths, i.e. /the/path.
After a lot of trial-and-error, and also suggested by Philippe, I found out that the forward slash needed to be doubled. I still don't understand exactly why, because I also tried enclosing it in single quites (') which should never be interpreted in any way after variable expansion, so it is happening somewhere else.
This works as expected:
DBPATH='/c/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.42.34433/bin/Hostx64/x64/dumpbin.exe' 
EXE_ARGS=" //dependents //nologo some.exe"
eval "${DBPATH} ${EXE_ARGS}"

# This also works!
# Notice removal of backslashes and change of quotes:
DBPATH='/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.42.34433/bin/Hostx64/x64/dumpbin.exe'
"${DBPATH}" ${EXE_ARGS}

PS. I'm happy to accept an alternative answer if there's some better explanation on this difference.

This feature is called path conversion and is explained here and here.

You don't need eval here, just "${DBPATH}" ${EXE_ARGS}

@Philippe In MSYS MINGW64, eval  is needed, in Cygwin it is not, which is how this entire question got started. Please note the differences between the Bash versions people use. I'm not using git-bash (and never intend to) so I have no idea what version they use in there.  You can check with: [CTRL+x] [CTRL+v], or with echo "$BASH_VERSION".  Then you can also check if your bash suffers from the $() sanitation bug.
In Cygwin both of the following works: (a) PS1='$(date) \$ '  and (b) PS1='$(date) \n\$ '. In MSYS the second fails.

More context to that ^^ issue, can be found here.

Please remove backslashes in DBPATH, and try my command again, and post any error messages.

@not2qubit "Git bash" is just MSYS bash, as I explained before. Ctrl+x, Ctrl+v gives me for example GNU bash, version 5.2.26(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys). May I point it out that we don't know what version you have, though, maybe you should add that to your question/answer as well!

Yes, I have 5.2.37(1)-release for MSYS, and 5.2.21(1)-release for Cygwin. I was looking at the recent change log for Bash (links in other QA), and they did a bunch of work on the command parser. As MSYS is using ~last version, it is likely that the funky behavior is due to some kind of regression.

@Philippe Tried and it fails with: No such file or directory.

Copy/paste this command to see if you still have problem : '/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.41.34120/bin/Hostx64/x64/dumpbin.exe' //dependents some.exe

@Philippe Yes, that works.  BTW. You can easily try this for yourselves. Just install the MSYS base package. NOTE: MSVC version was just updated...

I tried already and "${DBPATH}" ${EXE_ARGS} works.

@Philippe Yes, you're right! My bad. I didn't pay attention to the quotes. "${DBPATH} ${EXE_ARGS}" fails, whereas: "${DBPATH}" ${EXE_ARGS} works!  Great! (And without the backslashes.)
